# SASS Refusal to run despite (seemingly) being correctly written

Tags: sass, live-sass-compiler

this is the full code of the SASS file ive written, it is properly linked to a corresponding HTML file. despite this live SASS compiler will repeatedly kick up an error message also shown:

```
.title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    .text {
        overflow-wrap: normal;
        }
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    }
```

Personal information has been ofcource removed

```
Change detected - 3/24/2024, 4:34:29 PM
index.sass
--------------------
Compilation Error
Error: Expected newline.
  ╷
1 │ .title {
  │        ^
  ╵
  c:\Users\[Name]\Desktop\[other name]\index.sass 1:8  root stylesheet
```

I do not understand the issue particularly when comparing to my older work which does not trigger the same error.

i cant see what to do to fix this, especially given my older code is writen in seemingly the same way.

I use visual studio with the live SASS compiler installed.

Comment: It is likely you have configured your SASS compiler in "SASS intended syntax" mode instead of "SCSS syntax". https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/

Comment: i was thinking it was a complier issue aswell